# How do you set the class for only the first element in a handlebars foreach loop in emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am working on an emberjs app which will dynamically create n number of buttons based on my model. To do this, I use a foreach in my template to loop through my model and create a button for each element in the model.

```
{{#each model.zones as |zone|}}
       <li><a id="{{zone.zone_id}}" {{action 'setData' zone.currenttemp zone.setpoint zone.mode zone.zone_id on='click'}} class="zones">{{zone.zone_name}}: {{zone.currenttemp}}&deg;F</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

Each button has belongs to the class "zones" but I want only the first button to be a part of the class "active" when the app loads. I understand that the emberjs handlebars does not support the @first operator so I am not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`each` block comes with `index` variable, and you can combine with `if` inline helper

```
{{#each model.zones as |zone index|}}
       <li><a id="{{zone.zone_id}}" {{action 'setData' zone.currenttemp zone.setpoint zone.mode zone.zone_id on='click'}} class={{if index 'zones' 'active'}}>{{zone.zone_name}}: {{zone.currenttemp}}&deg;F</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

If you would like to have some other check then you can install [ember-truth-helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers) addon.

```
class={{if (eq index 0) 'active' 'zones'}}
```

Comment: I updated with if helper. for the first index 0 it will  be evaluate as `false` so `active` class will be applied and for remaining it will evaluate to `true` so `zones` class will be applied... [Twiddle sample](https://ember-twiddle.com/94394199278453d05bda24fd4a244f47?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) to demonstrate